# Windows license in VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, license

I am trying to understand how Windows 10 licensing works, with virtual machines in context. I want to run several Windows VMs in Virtualbox, using retail Windows 10 Pro licenses. But I don't want to buy a new license when I rebuild the VM, nor do I want to call Microsoft to ask them to reset the license so it works on new hardware. I can see Virtualbox supports something along the lines of

```
VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/DmiSystemSerial" "#######"
```

Is this something I can use to persist the system UUID across rebuilds? And more importantly, will Windows registration recognize this as being the same hardware it was previously installed on, and will I avoid the activation key trouble, typically associated with new hardware?

(fwiw I can handle the technical and implementation aspects of above no issues)

Comment: Retail licenses can be reused. Your question makes sense only if you're considering OEM licenses.

Comment: Dunno. I just hate Windows and all these idiotic scenarios it presents on a regular basis. Paying for an operating system is just so yesterday. How is that even a business model?